# How to resolve SQL Server deadlocks - once changing order and shortening queries is exhausted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-deadlocks

i have two hypothetical queries:

```
UPDATE BankAccounts SET HomePhone = '+1 252-555-0912' 
WHERE AccountNumber = 14400000619
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM BankAccounts 
WHERE HomePhone = '555-1212'
```

on a hypothetical table with no extra indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE BankAccounts 
( 
   AccountNumber bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   FirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   MiddleName nvarchar(50) NULL,
   LastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   HomePhone varchar(50) NULL,
   IsClosed tinyint DEFAULT 0
)
```

and everything will be great. If i add an index on `HomePhone`:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_BankAccounts_HomePhone ON BankAccounts 
( HomePhone)
```

Now my `SELECT` statement can be a **deadlock** victim:

> Tranasction (Process ID 169) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

The common suggestions are to:

- access tables in the same order
- keep transactions as short as possible

Except in this case:

- i am access the (one) table in the same order (1 choose 1 is 1)
- the transactions are a *single statement*; i cannot get any shorter than that

What's the long-term solution to eliminate deadlocks like this?

i was considering changing my **transaction isolation level** to `READ UNCOMMITTED` (i.e. eliminating integrity), but because i'm actually dealing with a financial system i'm hesitant to allow a customer to withdraw his entire balance twice.

The only other solution i can find comes from [KB Article 83252](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524):

> ### SQL Server technical bulletin - How to resolve a deadlock
>
> ...deadlocks cannot be avoided. That is why the front-end application should be designed to handle deadlocks.
>
> In a well designed application, the front-end application should trap for the 1205 error, reconnect to SQL Server, and then re-submit the transaction.

Which i guess is saying: *"can't win; don't try"*

Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can't win; don't try

That's right. You're seeing probably a [read-write](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/) deadlock (w/o the deadlock graph is only speculation on our part). The reverse order access occurs exactly *because* you're doing the right thing (ie. you do have the right index). Even if you access different keys (look up one phone, update another) you are still playing [a game of probabilities](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215/) due to hash collisions.

You can either accept deadlocks or resort to [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345124%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) model.

Answer (score 5):

If you replace the `SELECT *` with a column list (or consider all columns) and then add them to the index as `INCLUDE`d [columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190806.aspx), then the `SELECT` query will not need to query the clustered index to complete. The `SELECT` can then always run to completion.

If you don't want to do that, then rather than changing the whole isolation level, I'd consider whether a [locking hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187373.aspx) on the `SELECT` is appropriate. Whether the appropriate hint is `NOLOCK` or `READPAST` is something you'd need to carefully consider (In an ideal world, there would be a way to specify `READPAST` but gain information on whether any skipping of rows actually occurred).

Of course, `SNAPSHOT` [isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130975.aspx) might also be considered (if there are no locks, there are no deadlocks).

---

(A glutton for punishment might also consider using `TABLOCKX` on the `SELECT` statement. It'll prevent the deadlock and ensure you read a row if it exists, at a massive penalty for concurrency)

Comment: In large Warehouse applications I've "resolved" some nasty deadlock issues by serializing the offending actions. Each of those actions try to lock the same singular record. I suppose this is equivalent to your TABLOCKX?

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh - yes, it's effectively a local way of asking for serialization.